# Is there a way to make angular library backward compatible?

Tags: angular, angular12, angular-library

I created a angular library using angular version 12 and removed the peer dependencies of angular and tried to install the library on angular version 11. The library got installed but while using the library I am getting error in console

"node_modules/jjwins-pagination/lib/pagination.module.d.ts:5:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/POLUS/Sample/ang-11/page/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'. 5 static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<PaginationModule, never>;"

Every answers are welcomed. Thank you in advance.